# cannot move out of `*response` which is behind a shared reference with Rust while parsing a json response

Tags: json, rust, reqwest

I'm a newbie that is trying to make a simple email parser, but I'm facing the usual newcomers' problems with the borrowing stuff in Rust.

I'm trying to make compile the following code that wants to parse a json response with `reqwest` into my struct `MessagesListResponse` and then I just want to return a Vec of strings only containing the mapped ids:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
struct MessagesListResponse{
    messages: Vec<MessageId>
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
struct MessageId{
    id: String,
    thread_id: String
}


#[async_trait]
impl MessageGetter for GmailMessageGetter{

    async fn get_message_ids(&self) -> Vec<String> {
        

        let url = "https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=from%3Awebank%40webank.it%20subject%3Aautorizzato%20pagamento".to_owned();
        
        dbg!(&url);
        let response = &self.client.get(url).send().await.unwrap();

        _ = &response.error_for_status_ref().unwrap();
        let msg_list_response = response.json::<MessagesListResponse>().await.unwrap();
        msg_list_response.messages.into_iter().map(|message_id| message_id.id).collect()
    }
    
}
```

unfortunately I keep getting the error

```
cannot move out of `*response` which is behind a shared reference
```

at the line

```
let msg_list_response = response.json::<MessagesListResponse>().await.unwrap();
```

but I'm not understanding how to make it work because the response type `reqwest::async_impl::response` is not cloneable and the `response.json` method consumes the response. Can I get some help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why is the fact that the [`Response::json`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.json) method consumes the response a problem? In your example, it is not.

Comment: `response` has type `&reqwest::async_impl::response` because *you* borrowed it at the line `let response = &...`. Try removing the ampersand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an unnecessary reference here.

```rs
let response = &client.get(url).send().await.unwrap();
```

Remove it, and your code works.

```rs
let response = client.get(url).send().await.unwrap();
```

The assignment and reference here are unnecessary and do nothing.

```rs
_ = &response.error_for_status_ref().unwrap();
```

You can remove them.

```rs
response.error_for_status_ref().unwrap();
```

The `.to_owned()` at the end of the URL is also unnecessary. You should remove it.

Those are the only issues, but another way to write this is as one big method chain.

```rs
client
    .get(url)
    .send()
    .await
    .unwrap()
    .error_for_status()
    .unwrap()
    .json::<MessagesListResponse>()
    .await
    .unwrap()
    .messages
    .into_iter()
    .map(|message_id| message_id.id)
    .collect()
```

Comment: thank you @drewtato, now it works. Removing the ampersand from &self.client.get did the job; this makes understand how less I'm understanding Rust .
I was trying to understand why the get method accepts &self as first parameter but by passing it just self.client still works...

Comment: @exrezzo ahh, I see what you were going for. So there's two things. `&` has less precedence than `.`, so `&client.get(url)` is the same as `&(client.get(url))`, not `(&client).get(url)`. And `.` will automatically remove or add references in order to find a method, so you don't need to add them manually.